# How do I move the unordered ahref links to the center of navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I would like to shift the unordered a href links to the center of the navigation bar. However, I have tried to text-align: center but it still could not work.

Below is the codes I have tried.

```css
/* Navigation bar design */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#333;
  }
  
  li {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
  
  li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
  
li a:hover {
    background-color: #b0b0b0;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `display: flex;` and
`justify-content: center;` on `ul` to center align all the links.

```css
/* Navigation bar design */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#333;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  li {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
  
  li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
  
li a:hover {
    background-color: #b0b0b0;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add these 3 lines to your CSS file, inside the ul tag:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#333;

    /*--  add these lines  --*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below CSS to ul

```
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center; to the UI
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```css
nav {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#333;
}
  
li {
float: left;
color: white;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;

}
  
li a {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 3px;
}
  
li a:hover {
background-color: #b0b0b0;

}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="register.html">Register</a>. 
</li>
<li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a>. 
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I works however only left the 3 links in the middle with small width of the black background 

Comment: Try putting less font-size